# how to select div customName

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have a situation in my page i don't have any clue other than this 2 clue to `target`

```
<div itemscope>
 some <html>
........
</div>
```

how can i `target` `div` having `itemscope` i,e `<div itemscope>`

suppose i have structure like this

```
    <div itemscope>
      <a hrfe="http://www.a.com">a.com</a>
    </div>

    <div itemscope type="tang">
      <a hrfe="http://www.b.com">b.com</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a hrfe="http://www.c.com">c.com</a>
    </div>


    <div>
      <a hrfe="http://www.d.com">d.com</a>
    </div>
```

**PLEASE SUGGEST ME WHAT THIS KIND OF SELECTOR IS CALLED SO THAT I CAN SEARCH IT ON STACKOVERFLOW**

```js
var allDivWith_itemscope = $('div[i don"t know what else]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div itemscope>
  <a hrfe="http://www.a.com">a.com</a>
</div>
<div itemscope type="tang">
  <a hrfe="http://www.b.com">b.com</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a hrfe="http://www.c.com">c.com</a>
</div>


<div>
  <a hrfe="http://www.d.com">d.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: my `div` of intrest is where ever the `itemscope` is present

Comment: _hrfe_??? really?

Comment: A simple $('[itemscope]') will select your desired div.

Comment: content inside `<div itemscope>` might be variable with each `div` i  used `href` is just for `example`

Comment: Search for `attribute selector` ...

Comment: @Zagonine, my `test case` is posted `snippet` by me

Comment: @Satpal, you are `Wrong` here to `mark` it as `duplicate` i know what `custom tag is`  but here `scenario` is different if you have `solution` provide it then `mark` it as `duplicate` PLEASE

Comment: @user5405873 See https://jsfiddle.net/y6h6Lcz4/ and its a duplicate `$('div[itemscope]')` is the solution

Comment: The solution is pretty simple. Using `$('div[itemscope]')` gives you the object. Use the object returned by it.

Comment: @Satpal, thanks for the `fiddle` i always `enjoy` your `answer` thanks once `again`

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two things i want to mention:

1. You have a typo with `href` attribute.
2. You should use `data-*` prefix for custom attributes.

---

So, on basis of these you can change to this:

```
<div data-itemscope>
```

Now in js/jquery/css you can do this:

```
// css
div[data-itemscope]{
  properties:values;
}

// javascript
document.querySelector('div[data-itemscope]')

//jquery
$('div[data-itemscope]')
```

Comment: it is a dynamic `content` obtained from our client , they do have `div` as exactly as this `<div itemscope></div>` they did it to avoid `content scrapping`